# How to use 'where' in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In sql,we can use 'where' to select any data that we want.
How to do the same thing in firestore, I use if statement but it seems doesn't work

Comment: The documentation shows examples of how to limit queries based on some criteria.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to select a specific user from users collection

```
angularFirestore.collection('users', ref => ref.where('username', '==', 'doe'))
```

You can join multiple where clause

```
angularFirestore.collection('users', 
                             ref => ref.where('username', '==', 'doe')
                                       .where('age', '>=', '20'))
```

But you can use range comparison only on one filed.

**Right:**

```
angularFirestore.collection('users', 
                             ref => ref.where('age', '<=', '40')
                                       .where('age', '>=', '20'))
```

**Wrong:**

```
angularFirestore.collection('users', 
                             ref => ref.where('earning', '>=', '40000')
                                       .where('age', '>=', '20'))
```